# My posts are getting to Auto draft when I try to Publish

Tags: posts, errors, publish, draft

My posts on [my site](https://topvpn.review) are getting into auto-draft mode when I try to publish it.

So far, I have tried the following:
1. Change the theme.
2. Disable all plugins
3. Disabled widgets using functions.php.

Not sure what is causing this.
Can you please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Though you proceeded with some of the debugging techniques, can you please proceed with [some other also](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/debug/info)? Hopefully, inshALLAH, with the result somebody can assist you if you can't find what's the issue.

Comment: On which user role currently you are?

Comment: @TejasGajjar Admin role

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following in your wp-config.php

```
define( 'AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL', 3600 );     // autosave 1x per hour
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', false );    // no revisions
```

What this would do disable auto-save and post-revisions. Try with that, if it works could be your then it could be your internet or hosting conflicts.

Comment: I tried this. But still the same issue :(

Comment: Can you give details to your hosting details. We need to debug this. One way would be using Duplicator or any other tool to create a local copy of your site and try. I am sure that you have tried using incognito as well or an another browser?